# Как изменить текст, получаемый JSON'oм?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток. Мне нужно изменить текст получаемого JSON из php, изменить нужно только значения ключа "text", не задев другие ключи в словаре.
Мой JSON:

```
NSString *googleString7 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://mysite.ru/?go=api&act=message&id=",idLoad];
    NSURL *googleURL7 = [NSURL URLWithString:googleString7];
    NSString *googlePage7 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:googleURL7
                                                     encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding
                                                        error:&error3];

    NSMutableString *dat7 = [NSMutableString stringWithString: googlePage7];

    NSString *dat5 = dat7;
    NSData *allcur = [dat5 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *responseD = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:allcur options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:responseD])
    {
        NSArray *array = [responseD objectForKey:@"locations"];

        [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *msg, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
         {
             Message *message = [[Message alloc] init];
             int typees = [[msg objectForKey:@"type"] intValue];

             if (typees == 2) {
                 typees = 0;
             }
             else
             {
                 typees = 1;
             }
             message.fromMe = typees;
             message.text = [msg objectForKey:@"text"];

             NSDateFormatter *dateTo = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
             [dateTo setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
             NSDate *dateOnl = [dateTo dateFromString:[msg objectForKey:@"date"]];
             message.date = dateOnl;

             [result addObject:message];
         }];
    }
```

Можно было бы после `message.text = [msg objectForKey:@"text"];` обрабатывать его, но т.к. обрабатывать я буду тоже через сервер, пост запросом, это очень сильно будет нагружать сервер и задерживать работу программы, хотелось бы одним махом обработать все значения ключей "text". Если попытаться обработать JSON перед запихиванием в массив, то ничего не выйдет, т.к. текст JSON выглядит так: `\u041a\u0410\u041a`.

Подскажите, как бы сделали вы?

Answer (score 1):

"Если попытаться обработать JSON перед запихиванием в массив, то ничего не выйдет, т.к. текст JSON выглядит так: \u041a\u0410\u041a." - это вам NSLog так показывает :) На самом деле \u041a - это юникодный символ (русская буква). 
После message.text = [msg objectForKey:@"text"]; делайте с текстом что хотите.

PS. Загрузка методом - NSString stringWithContentsOfURL - это ужасно.

Comment: 1. А какой метод вы используете?
2. "После message.text ", говорю же, мне нужно text обрабатывать переводчиком с сервера, если так делать с каждым message.text, это будет сильно грузить сервер, т.к. в JSON 20 ключей text, 20 раз отправлять POST с текстом? Нагрузит сервер и программу.

Comment: 1.Используйте какой-нибудь асинхронный вариант загрузки, например, NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest ...
2. По поводу апи сервера мы сами должны догадываться? Как именно он принимает данные на вход, в виде отдельных слов или можно послать массив слов и на каждое будет перевод или еще как? А без этого вам никто ничего посоветовать не сможет - просто не понятно что делать. И, кстати, "Нагрузит ... программу" прямое следствие пункта 1

Comment: Я с утра хотел ответить на ваш вопрос, но потом плюнул, т.к. не понимял, чего вы, собственно, хотите, зачем что-то менять, куда-то посылать и т.п. Теперь оказывается, что речь о переводе. Пишите вопросы уже корректно, вам же нужен ответ, а подробности, что и как, у вас приходится клещами тянуть.